# Generating correlated random variables with normal distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

[This site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of) and [this site](http://www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/) provide some background as to what I am trying to achieve, but with some  variations in what is required. First I want three random variables with a normal distribution, however they are correlated as in $d_i= c a_i +(1-c) b_i$, where $c$ is the correlation factor, and $(a_i, b_i, d_i)$ are the variables. The constraint $b_i < d_i < a_i$ is a requirement.

Here I have  a Monte Carlo based simulation that yields all three variables which satisfies the criteria mentioned above:

```
RaN[m_, s_, co_] := 
 Module[{me = m, sd = s, c = co}, 
  q1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[me, sd]]; 
  q2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[me, sd]]; 
      p = c*q1 + (1 - c)*q2; 
  If[TrueQ[q2 < p < q1], {q1, q2, p}, RaN[m, s, co]]]

Manipulate[
 ListPointPlot3D[Table[RaN[0, 1, cr], {i, 1000}]], {cr, 0.005, 0.995}]
```

[image: some points]

However this is not an optimized code. It can be expensive time-wise, and also there is the possibility of running into recursion depth problems if total runs is increased.

My question is: Are there better ways of seeking, not just 3 correlated variables, but a sequence of $N$ variables such that the variables $a_i$ is the highest and $b_i$ is the lowest numbers. The site mentioned earlier points to a technique that involves matrices. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to have the same output properties than your function and doesn't suffer the "recursive trap", but I'm not sure about the "statistical truth" of your statements `RaN[m_, s_, c_] := 
  Append[#, c*#[[1]] + (1 - c)*#[[2]]] &@
   Sort@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[m, s], {2}];`

Comment: If I change "2" to "5",  I get {-0.669003, -0.00770918, 0.253854, 0.25824, 0.517137, -0.66239}. How do you get  3 numbers sandwiched between the lowest & highest......

Comment: Or much faster `RaN[m_, s_, c_, n_] := 
  Append[#, c*#[[1]] + (1 - c)*#[[2]]] & /@ (Sort /@ 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[m, s], {n, 2}]);

Manipulate[ListPointPlot3D[RaN[0, 1, cr, 1000]], {cr, 0.005, 0.995}]`

Comment: Looks gd! How to generalize to sequence of N numbers

Comment: I don't fully understand if the way you're generating the "correlated" rvs is sound. I prefer to leave and see what other more statistically-savvy users have to say.

Comment: The way of generating correlated nos is based on the first part of this http://www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/

Comment: he! I wasn't arguing about the method, but excusing me because of my lack of understanding :)

Comment: `TransformedDistribution[c u + (1 - c) v, {u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ], v \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ]}]` shows that your unrestricted $d_i$ is a normal variate, but I'm not sure the distribution is still normal after your restriction.

Comment: @J.M. For example `PDF[TransformedDistribution[
  Max[u, v], {u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[m, s], 
   v \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[m, s]}], x]`

Comment: @bel, that is, `OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[μ, σ], 2}, 2]`; certainly not normal.

Comment: @J.M. Then _probably_ the Normality condition for all vars can't be requested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Analytic approach:

```
Manipulate[
SeedRandom["five"]; 
ListPointPlot3D[
 RandomVariate[
  TransformedDistribution[{a, b, c*a + (1 - c)*b}, {{a, b} \[Distributed] 
   OrderDistribution[BinormalDistribution[r], {1, 2}]}], 10^3], 
PlotLabel -> Row[{"c = ", c, " | ", "r = ", r}]], 
{{c, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{r, 0}, -.99, .99}]
```

[image: Out]

Comment: Neat code. Why "five" in SeedRandom?

Comment: "five" is a random choice whim :) seed is fixed to focus on the dependence on c and r.

Answer (score 5):

You only have to deal with choosing $a$ and $b$ because if $c$ (a weighting factor not a correlation factor) is between 0 and 1, then $d$ has to be between $a$ and $b$.  (If $c$ is outside that range, I don't think you can get there from here.)

What you've used above is a type of rejection sampling.  If the means are the same for $a$ and $b$, then you're only wasting about half of the samples which doesn't seem too inefficient but you could speed up the process by generating a little over twice the number of needed observations at one time and then select the first $n$ that satisfy the desired ordering.

If $a$ and $b$ are selected from a bivariate normal distribution with the same means (`mu`) and same standard deviations (`sigma`) and a correlation coefficient (`rho`), then the desired triplet can be determined as the following:

$$(\min(a,b), c\max(a,b)+(1-c)\min(a,b), \max(a,b))$$

Here is some *Mathematica* code that can certainly be made more efficient:

```
(* Set some parameters for a bivariate normal and take a random sample; *)
mu = 0;    (* Mean *)
sigma=1;   (* Standard deviation *)
rho=-0.5;  (* This correlation coefficient can be between -1 and +1 *)

n=1000;    (* Sample size *)
raw=RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{mu,mu},{sigma,sigma},rho],n];

(* Create a table with the minimum (b) and maximum (a) of each pair 
   of random samples and a placeholder for d *)
data=Table[{Min[raw[[i,All]]],0,Max[raw[[i,All]]]},{i,n}];

(* Determine the weighted average of a and b *)
c = 0.4;
data[[All,2]]=c data[[All,3]]+(1-c)data[[All,1]];

(* Plot the resulting samples *)
ListPointPlot3D[data, BoxRatios->{1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Random sample]

Note that none of the elements of the triplet will have a normal distribution but the triplet is generated from a bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: I think you forgot to include `c`; anyway, `data = With[{d = Sort /@ raw}, MapThread[Riffle, {d, d.{1 - c, c}}]]`.

Comment: @J.M.  Ooops!  Still working on cutting-and-pasting properly.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've added the definition for `c`.

Comment: Nimble code! Just wish the elements satisfy normal distribution. Is there a quick way to check if a distribution is normal (even though this is not part of the query)

Comment: @thils.  Therapy for removing a feeling of dependence on normality is not as quick but better in the long run.  But more seriously, why do you need to have the variables have a normal distribution?  That should probably be another question or a discussion in chat.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Because of normal distribution's omnipresence...its  almost everywhere

Comment: @thils, black swans are far more common than you think. Seriously, consider the therapy Jim mentions for weaning you off from the Gaussian shackles…

Answer (score 3):

I am **not** certain what the ultimate aim here (in particular correlation relationship). I post this in the event it may be helpful. In the following a and b are independent (standardized) normal random variables that are correlated with (standardized) normal variable d but in such a way that when a is poorly correlated b is highly correlated.

```
mn[c_] := 
 MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 
   0}, {{1, 0, 1 - c}, {0, 1, c}, {1 - c, c, 1}}]
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Show[ListPointPlot3D[RandomVariate[mn[1 - c], 10000], 
     AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "d"}, BaseStyle -> 20], 
    Plot3D[{c, 1 - c}.{x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, 
     PlotStyle -> {Pink, Opacity[0.3]}], ImageSize -> 400],
   Show[ListPointPlot3D[RandomVariate[mn[1 - c], 10000], 
     AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "d"}, BaseStyle -> 20, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y < z < x]], 
    Plot3D[{c, 1 - c}.{x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, 
     PlotStyle -> {Pink, Opacity[0.3]}], ImageSize -> 400]
   }],
 {c, 0.05, 0.995, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

The lower plot is the truncated sample based on constraint in OP.

Some conditional probabilities illustrating the relationship between variables and "correlation" c.

```
tab = Table[{j, 
    NProbability[
     z > 0.5 \[Conditioned] x > 0.5, {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
      mn[1 - j]],
    NProbability[
     z > 0.5 \[Conditioned] y > 0.5, {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
      mn[1 - j]]}, {j, 0.05, 0.95, 0.05}];
ListPlot[{tab[[All, {1, 2}]], tab[[All, {1, 3}]]}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {None, {Probability[x > 0.5, 
     x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"P(d>0.5|a>0.5)", "P{d>0.5|b>0.5}"}]
```

[image]

with gridline probability P(Z>0.5), Z is N(0,1) and symmetry around c=0.5

I re-iterate I am not sure what is the aim and whether this post has any relevance. I am happy to delete for lack of relevance.

Comment: Close to what I am after. The aim: correlated random events are  part of the essence of quantum entanglement...with specific distributions you can proceed to explore the bizarre quantum world

Comment: @thils I would not accept my answer as it is just exploratory and wait for better answers...I hope you can play but I am sure others will have closer and answers rather than longer comment :)